# What do I need to add to this desktop file to start in a specific virtual desktop?

Tags: gnome, workspaces, autostart, workspace-switcher

I've been searching for documentation for the key,value pairs in the gnome desktop autostart files. I have 4 virtual desktops/workspaces that I switch between and I want to autostart applications in 3 of them. This file only starts the application on in the first workspace, what do I need to add?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry 83x26+425+0
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Terminal 1
Name=Terminal
Comment[en_US]=First Terminal
Comment=First Terminal
```

Where do I find the documentation on the key, value pairs?

If this has been answered, please point me to the answer and close the question.

Comment: This question was answered in the Unix Linux group
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265087/can-someone-point-me-to-documentation-for-key-value-pairs-for-autostart-desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Key, Value pairs that I was looking for did not supply the answer, I had to install the auto move windows extension and then configure the applications I wanted to automatically move to different desktops. This method only works on applications installed by get-apt, it does not work on multiple gnome-terminal sessions.

```
As described at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/gnome-shell-make-applications-start-on.html, the solution is to install the auto move extension and then use tweek tool to modify some settings. To install the gnome sell auto move extension:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

For Ubuntu 11:10:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-auto-move-windows
```

For Ubuntu 12:04 or later

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Once the auto move shell extension is install start tweek tool and select Extensions
[Screen shot of tweek tool with Extensions selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxp6c.png)

Then select the settings gear on Auto move windows. This provides a dialog where you can add applications and then specify the desktop you want to use as shown below.

[screen shot of the Auto move windows dialog allowing you to move applications to another desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b0JR.png)

You can also use the dconf editor to select the default desktop.

Comment: I would *really* appreciate if you'd include the essence of what was your solution. A link to a post that links to a solution (which is still to search for in the final link) is not the most robust way of answering a question . If you do, I'll upvote both the question and the answer :)

Comment: Jacob, I have updated the answer to show how to automatically start applications on a specified desktop.